# How to fix `returns a value referencing data owned by the current function` when using std::str::Chars in Rust

Tags: string, rust, struct, iterator, ownership

I have a function `tk_from_file`  that reads a file, and returns a struct `Tokenizer`, with a `Peekable<Chars<'a>>` over the contents of that file.

The variable `content` is from the `Result<String>` returned from `std::fs::read_to_string`

However, when I try to create the struct and return it, I get the following error (E0515):

```
30 |           return Tokenizer {
   |  ________________^
31 | |             content: content.clone().chars().peekable(),
   | |                      --------------- temporary value created here
32 | |             loc: FileLocation {
33 | |                 file: path,
...  |
36 | |             }
37 | |         };
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I have tried using it with `clone()` and without, as well as `clone()` on the Chars iterator in addition to the String, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you `clone` this `String` or not. `String` created in this function is *owned* by this function, therefore you cannot return any references to it from the function, because when the stack frame of the function is popped the `String` will be dealocated and you will have a dangling pointer, which is a big no no in rust world.

If you want to reference this `String` created when reading file you *must* return owned `String` from the function somehow and give an ownership of it to the caller. One solution would be to store a `String` inside `Tokenizer` struct and provide a method on it that would borrow a `String` and return iterator.

```rust
struct Tokenizer {
    content: String,
    ...
}

impl Tokenizer {
    fn content(&self) -> Peekable<Chars<'_>> {
        self.content.chars().peekable()
    }
}
```

With following structure you can pass ownership of file content to the caller and allow them to borrow it for as long as they want. You can read more about ownership and borrowing in [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) chapter of The Book.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Using a getter function for this makes so much more sense, yeah :)

Comment: @Basil This is not a "getter" function strictly speaking, because it doesn't return `&String` but processes it somehow. I named it `content` for the sole reason I couldn't think of any better name on the fly. ;)

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right oops